Nextjs handle POST redirect and read params
As you know by default browser send GET requests and server returns the pages, but in my case, i doing some request to remote server and need to get some response, but server redirect me back to my page via POST request with some data.
Is that possible to handle POST request in Nextjs application?
When server redirects me i see this error because its POST instead of GET.


Is that possible to enable POST requests on Client app?

I'm not sure if this is the solution. But I googled and someone had a problem with server actions and this is the link that solved the issue for him. maybe it helps you too: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/58019#issuecomment-1795133629

@ArashJahanBakhshan no its not(

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/serverActions was the solution for incoming POST redirect.
